# チャットbotについて

Tags: javascript

チャットbotを作るにはどんな言語が最適ですか？やっぱりjavascriptですか？
その言語を勉強してbotを作りたいので教えてください。
追記:
たとえば、チャットで何か文字を受信したら、自動的に文字を送信する機能が欲しいです。javascriptで作りたいのですが、初心者なので関数など教えてください。

Comment: ご質問がクローズされました。私の回答の方でも書きましたが、どのような動作をするチャットbotを作ろうとされていて、どんなことができれば「良い」のかを質問文に追記くださるとありがたいです。

Comment: 分かりました！。

Comment: ここでいう「チャット」というのはどういうチャットを想定されていますか？　たとえばインターネット越しにするものなのかどうかも分かりません。オリジナルのチャットなのか何かのサービスのチャットなのか、どちらでしょうか。「JavaScriptで作りたい」という形に質問が変わったようなので、そのあたりも含めつつ新しい質問として投稿いただくのが良さそうです。

Answer (score 1):

チャットbotは、入出力ができるプログラミング言語であれば大抵作れます。どんなチャットbotを想定されているかも、どういうことができればより最適なのかも、一般的な基準が存在しないため質問文に書いてくださらないと「大体どんな言語でもOKです」より客観的なことを言うのは難しそうです。まずは質問者さんが気になる言語でとりあえずそのチャットbotを作ってみて、その上で具体的にどういうことがしたいのかを考えるところからかな、と思います。